# How can I regulate the motion of individual images and text elements as I navigate through the vertical scrolling of my website?

Tags: html, css

I possess a diverse range of content, including text, images, videos, and 3D content. I am curious to know if it is possible to overlay each of these content types and adjust their positions relative to one another. Additionally, I would like to have control over their movement while scrolling vertically. Could you please advise me on the appropriate method to achieve this desired effect?

I was trying to create different division and assigned each content but still the movement was on the same. it moves all together. I am looking to make different timing for each content while I scroll up and down!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your "question" is well below the standard required on this site. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular - I would also recommend you take the [tour]